# Importing a csv file into database mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, import-from-csv

Well my question seems simple

I have my csv file located in /etc/myData.csv

I have my code

```
USE assessment; 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_data; 
CREATE TABLE test_data (
    ProductID int,
    ProductName varchar(255)
);

mysqlimport assessment  '/src/myData.csv';

SELECT * FROM test_data;
```

I tried `msqlimport` but it gives me syntax error.

I even tried this command

```
mysqlimport  --fields-terminated-by=, assessment  /src/test_data.csv ;
```

Again syntax error. What's wrong with it?

FYI: I already know `LOAD` command but I want to know other mysql command to import data.

Answer (score 0):

mysqlimport is intended to be run from the shell command line nor via the SQL interface.

If you have an SQL interface you can use [load data infile](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/src/myData.csv' INTO TABLE test_data;
```

But you need to make sure the file is readable by the dbms uid.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know that you need to run mysqlimport -command from command line. It's not a SQL command that you can run with in your other SQL commands. Actually mysqlimport is just a command line interface to LOAD INFILE so you should use that.

If you want to use mysqlimport following command should work. Before running the command, you should change the file name to test_data.csv to get the data to test_data table.

mysqlimport -u root -ppassword --local assessment '/src/test_data.csv'